# Application requires a JRE version

Tags: java, version, updates, launch4j

After update `Java` to `1.8.0_101` when I try to run my application (which after compilation is `.exe`) appear information `This application requires a Java Runtime Environment 1.8.0_40` and application not  running. I used `launch4j`

Someone have the same problem ? Any idea why after update `Java` it is shown ?

`pom.xml`

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
        <executable>${env.JAVA_HOME}</executable>
        <compilerArguments>
            <bootclasspath>${env.JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/rt.jar:${env.JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/jce.jar</bootclasspath>
        </compilerArguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

There is `launch4j` plugin configuration

```
 <plugin>
        <groupId>com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>launch4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>l4j-gui</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>launch4j</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <headerType>gui</headerType>
                    <outfile>target/App.exe</outfile>
                    <jar>target/App.jar</jar>
                    <priority>high</priority>
                    <errTitle>App</errTitle>
                    <classPath>
                        <mainClass>com.app.Main</mainClass>
                    </classPath>
                    <jre>
                        <minVersion>1.8.0_40</minVersion>
                    </jre>
                    <versionInfo>
                        <productName>App</productName>
                        <internalName>app</internalName>
                        <originalFilename>App.exe</originalFilename>                                    
                    </versionInfo>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
  </plugin>
```

**EDIT**

After change the `minVersion` to `1.8.0._101` it works but I am not satisfied with this, because when next version of `Java` (for example `1.8.0_102`) comes I will have to change this too...

Comment: What tool did you use to generate the `.exe`?

Comment: Compiling using `Intelij IDEA`

Comment: I don't think IDEA as an IDE can generate `.exe`-files (at least I haven't found anything indicating that it could). You might have some kind of java-exe-wrapper or something....

Comment: I used maven install, version `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.3.1`. It is possible that the problem is with maven version ?

Comment: Nope, that's also not the one (install plugin is used to deploy artifacts to the remote repository). But OK, now we know you are using maven, that leaves the question what plugin produces the exe. appassembler, launch4j or something different. And once we got this answered you should post the relevant section from your pom.xml.

Comment: I used `launch4j` in version `1.5.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is [a bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/launch4j/bugs/146/) in older launch4j-versions when the jre-version-number exceeds 100. So you have to use launch4j version 3.9 which should be in version 1.7.11 of the launch4j-plugin.